# Calculating BST time from Date object?

Tags: javascript, date, dst, timezone-offset

I've reviewed a few questions on similar topics already, but none of them address calculating a destination timezone, taking *its* DST (daylight savings time) into account. I'm trying to write a simple widget that displays a live local time of a specific timezone to anyone visiting the page. The timezone of interest is BST ([what is BST?](http://www.timeanddate.com/time/gmt-utc-time.html)), but if possible I'd love to see a generic implementation for any locale. Here's my attempt, using vanilla JavaScript:

```js
function getBST() {
    var date = new Date(),
        utc = date.getTime() + date.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000,
        local = new Date(utc), // this is GMT, not BST
        day = local.getDate(),
        mon = local.getMonth() + 1,
        year = local.getFullYear(),
        hour = local.getHours(),
        minute = ('0' + local.getMinutes()).slice(-2),
        second = ('0' + local.getSeconds()).slice(-2),
        suffix = hour < 12 ? 'AM' : 'PM';

    hour = (hour - 24) % 12 + 12;

    return mon + '/' + day + '/' + year + ', ' + hour + ':' + minute + ':' + second + ' ' + suffix;
}

setInterval(function () {
  document.body.textContent = getBST();
}, 1000);
```

Based on @RobG's answer, I've written this code:

```js
function resetDay(date) {
  date.setUTCMilliseconds(0);
  date.setUTCSeconds(0);
  date.setUTCMinutes(0);
  date.setUTCHours(1);

  return date;
}

function lastDay(date, day) {
  while (date.getUTCDay() !== day) {
    date.setUTCDate(date.getUTCDate() - 1);
  }

  return date;
}

function adjustDST(date, begin, end) {
  if (date >= begin && date < end) {
    date.setUTCHours(date.getUTCHours() + 1);
  }

  return date;
}

function updateBST() {
  var date = new Date();
  var begin = resetDay(new Date());

  begin.setUTCMonth(3, -1);
  begin = lastDay(begin, 0);

  var end = resetDay(new Date());

  end.setUTCMonth(10, -1);
  end = lastDay(end, 0);

  date = adjustDST(date, begin, end);

  var day = date.getUTCDate(),
    mon = date.getUTCMonth() + 1,
    year = date.getUTCFullYear(),
    hour = date.getUTCHours(),
    minute = ('0' + date.getUTCMinutes()).slice(-2),
    second = ('0' + date.getUTCSeconds()).slice(-2),
    suffix = hour < 12 ? 'AM' : 'PM';

  hour = (hour - 24) % 12 + 12;

  return mon + '/' + day + '/' + year + ', ' + hour + ':' + minute + ':' + second + ' ' + suffix;
}

setInterval(function () {
  document.body.textContent = updateBST();
}, 1000);
```

I tested the BST by pausing in the debugger and changing the month of the current date, and the output was an hour later so it seems to work properly. Thanks for all your help everyone!

Comment: I would suggest looking at a library like [Moment](http://momentjs.com/) and [Moment Timezone](http://momentjs.com/timezone/). Dates and time zones in JavaScript are notoriously hard, and writing your own is liable to be error-prone.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan—"*Dates and time zones in JavaScript are notoriously hard…*". No they aren't, it's just that there is a lot of poor information and people don't take the time to understand them. Dates are really very simple objects.

Comment: So, if they're not that hard, answer the question :P. In pure JavaScript, mind you, without reference to an external library.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan—I don't have time at the moment to write the code, but I've answers. I'll be back in about 10 hrs.

Comment: To be pedantic, let me say that "BST" is specifically UTC+1.  The United Kingdom is *sometimes* on BST, and *sometimes* on GMT.  If you're attempting to reconcile the transitions for a single time zone, you would refer to it as UK Time or London Time.  IANA uses the `Europe/London` identifier.  The idea of "convert to BST" would make me think you only wanted UTC+1, even if BST wasn't in effect.

Comment: @MattJohnson thanks for the clarification. I just meant UK time.

Comment: One other point - the string you are building has `m/d/y` format, but in the UK, they use `d/m/y`.

Comment: @RobG - "hard" is a relative term with regard to understanding.  Guys like you and I may find these things easy, but most do not - hence the large number of questions in this area.  Let me buy you a beverage of your choosing sometime and tell you some stories!  Cheers! :)

Comment: @PatrickRoberts - Reviewing your code some more - the comparison should be closed on the starting side: `(date >= begin && date < end)`.  Also, the time changes at 1:00 AM UTC, not at midnight, and be sure you are only working with dates from 1981 forward.  The DST rules were different before then.  (See the tzdb sources, or timeanddate.com if you want all the details.)

Comment: Oh - and I almost missed this - but you're only calculating based on the *current* year - so what you posted here is fine, but if `date` actually comes from somewhere else (such as a database), then you could be looking at old data from a prior year, in which case the dates you chose for DST *this year* won't help.  (starting to see why a library might be a better option?  If not - consider what happens in other time zones, such as those in the southern hemisphere where DST spans over the year boundary)

Comment: @MattJohnson thanks for all these pointers. I will most definitely correct the midnight issue, and the equality issue since those are easy to fix. But the others are edge cases that don't apply to my situation, so I'll disregard those for my solution.

Comment: Sure - just wanted to call them out for others that may come along and read this discussion.

Comment: @MattJohnson—great comments, I think dates are a lot simpler than bitwise operators and lookahead/behind regular expressions!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not difficult to support one timezone provided you know when it transitions in and out of daylight saving.

A javascript Date consists of a time value in UTC and a timezone offset based on the host system settings. So all you need to do is apply the timezone offset that you want to the UTC time and presto, there's your time in any timezone.

There is no standardised system for abbreviating time zones, though there are some defacto standards (e.g. [*IATA timezone codes*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Air_Transport_Association_code#IATA_timezone_codes) and [*IANA timezones*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database)). I guess by BST you mean British Summer Time, also known as British Daylight Time (BDT) and British Daylight Saving Time (BDST). It might also be Bangladesh Standard Time or Bougainville Standard Time which are also known as "BST".

There are various libraries (such as [*Moment Timezone*](http://momentjs.com/timezone/)) that use the IANA codes and can provide the time for any supported time zone for (more or less) any time.

BST starts at 01:00 UTC on the last Sunday in March and ends at 01:00 UTC on the last Sunday in October each year, so the algorithm is:

1. Create a new date based on the system's local settings (e.g. `new Date()`)
2. Create dates for the start and end of BST based on UTC values (for this year, 2016-03-27T01:00:00Z and 2016-03-30T02:00:00Z)
3. See if the current UTC time falls in that range
4. If so, add 1 hour to the UTC time of the date created in #1
5. Output a formatted string based on the date's UTC values

That's it, the only hard part is finding the appropriate Sunday dates. You don't need to consider the local timezone offset at all, since everything is based on UTC and Date objects are too.

Right now I don't have time to provide code, so have a go and I can get back to you in about 10 hrs.

#### Edit

So here's the code. The first two function are helpers, one gets the last Sunday in a month, the other formats an ISO 8601 string with offset. Most of the work is in those two functions. Hopefully the comments are sufficient, if more explanation is required, just ask.

I haven't included milliseconds in the string, feel free to add them if you want, add `+ '.' + ('00' + d.getUTCMilliseconds()).slice(-3)` before the offset part of the formatted string.

Note that the function will need to be modified if the dates for starting or stopping daylight saving are changed, but that is infrequent. Historic dates of course will need a small database of when daylight saving starts and stops for particular years and periods.

```js
/* Return a Date for the last Sunday in a month
** @param {number} year - full year number (e.g. 2015)
** @param {number} month - calendar month number (jan=1)
** @returns {Date} date for last Sunday in given month
*/
function getLastSunday(year, month) {
  // Create date for last day in month
  var d = new Date(year, month, 0);
  // Adjust to previous Sunday
  d.setDate(d.getDate() - d.getDay());
  return d;
}

/* Format a date string as ISO 8601 with supplied offset
** @param {Date} date - date to format
** @param {number} offset - offset in minutes (+east, -west), will be
**                          converted to +/-00:00
** @returns {string} formatted date and time
**
** Note that javascript Date offsets are opposite: -east, +west but 
** this function doesn't use the Date's offset.
*/
function formatDate(d, offset) {
  function z(n){return ('0'+n).slice(-2)}
  // Default offset to 0
  offset = offset || 0;
  // Generate offset string
  var offSign = offset < 0? '-' : '+';
  offset = Math.abs(offset);
  var offString = offSign + ('0'+(offset/60|0)).slice(-2) + ':' + ('0'+(offset%60)).slice(-2);
  // Generate date string
  return d.getUTCFullYear() + '-' + z(d.getUTCMonth()+1) + '-' + z(d.getUTCDate()) +
         'T' + z(d.getUTCHours()) + ':' + z(d.getUTCMinutes()) + ':' + z(d.getUTCSeconds()) +
         offString;
}

/* Return Date object for current time in London. Assumes
** daylight saving starts at 01:00 UTC on last Sunday in March
** and ends at 01:00 UTC on the last Sunday in October.
** @param {Date} d - date to test. Default to current
**                   system date and time
** @param {boolean, optional} obj - if true, return a Date object. Otherwise, return
**                        an ISO 8601 formatted string
*/
function getLondonTime(d, obj) {
  // Use provided date or default to current date and time
  d = d || new Date();

  // Get start and end dates for daylight saving for supplied date's year
  // Set UTC date values and time to 01:00
  var dstS = getLastSunday(d.getFullYear(), 3);
  var dstE = getLastSunday(d.getFullYear(), 10);
  dstS = new Date(Date.UTC(dstS.getFullYear(), dstS.getMonth(), dstS.getDate(),1));
  dstE = new Date(Date.UTC(dstE.getFullYear(), dstE.getMonth(), dstE.getDate(),1));
  // If date is between dstStart and dstEnd, add 1 hour to UTC time
  // and format using +60 offset
  if (d > dstS && d < dstE) {
    d.setUTCHours(d.getUTCHours() +1);
    return formatDate(d, 60);
  }
  // Otherwise, don't adjust and format with 00 offset
  return obj? d : formatDate(d);
}

document.write('Current London time: ' + getLondonTime(new Date()));
```

Comment: Thanks for the algorithm, I didn't realize you could ignore local offset, because most of the solutions I've seen actually take it into account.

Comment: Yes, it's just that the non–UTC methods use it by default. ;-)

Comment: So, you do need an external reference for those time zone offsets (especially for the general case, where you don't know the date in advance, since the dates of the offset change vary by historical year), which is where the difficulty lies, and why I mentioned it was difficult, and why I referenced the same library as you do, Moment Timezone.

Comment: I updated my question to show my vanilla implementation of the algorithm you provided. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @RobG - The problem with this approach is that the `Date` object in JavaScript will still think it's in the local time zone, and thus it may decide to "adjust" values that are near DST transitions in the local time zone.  If the target time zone's DST rules are significantly different, it can lead to an incorrect result.  Essentially, the flaw is between steps 4 and step 5 - in that if you add outside of the `Date` object you're fine - but if you go back to the `Date` object to produce the string result, it may fail.  (Moment avoids this BTW)

Comment: Fortunately, the code posted with the OP's update doesn't suffer from this problem, since he builds the string himself from parts from UTC-based properties, rather than relying on the `Date` object to do it.  This is quite a workaround, but it does work.  Just don't hand that `Date` object off to some other API, or it will probably do the wrong thing with it.

Comment: @MattJohnson—I think my algorithm works OK since I only use UTC values. It can also be done by adjusting the time value using the timezone offset and treating it like a UTC date, but I wanted to avoid that. Only lightly tested though.

Comment: Yes, agreed.  The only danger with the general approach (sometimes called "epoch shifting") is if you put it back into a `Date` object and rely on that object to do the formatting with `toString` or others methods.  Sometimes folks pass the `Date` object into another library, or to a UI control, and in those scenarios it catches the edge cases near DST boundaries.  So with very careful use, it works, but in the *general* case it can cause trouble.

Answer (score 7):

It's not possible in pure JS, just using the `Date` methods, but there's (of course) a lib for that: http://momentjs.com/timezone/

Example:

```
moment.tz("Europe/London").format(); // 2016-01-15T09:21:08-07:00
```

Comment: It's not my downvote either, but it is possible and moment.js and Moment Timezone are pure JS. ;-)

Comment: @RobG they might be "pure" but they're not "vanilla"

Comment: @RobG Well, every JS lib is pure JS I guess... maybe "pure" is not the best choice of word, what would you suggest ?

Comment: @Ilya I apologize, I don't know who's downvoting you, but I can no longer accept your answer because RobG provided exactly what I needed.

Comment: Well, that sucks, because in practice re-coding moment.js is a really bad idea I think, unless you have too much free time.

Comment: Before you added an example, it was simply "your answer lies elsewhere" which is not a good answer.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan, ok, fine, but it's more useful to comment so that the OP can improve his answer than to just downvote without explanation. And beside, "it"s easy to code yourself" is misguiding I think. Look at the moment.js code...

Comment: I agree with "not coding it yourself" (see my comments on the question and accepted answer). There is plenty of information about what makes a good (and bad) answer (e.g., [answer]), so I didn't feel like I needed to repeat it.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan what's missing is the "What makes a useful downvote" part ;-). Anyway, I've updated the answer from its crude 1rst version. Thanks for explaining.

Comment: @Ilya - FWIW - I upvoted.  But you should use `Europe/London` to fit the OP, and also you can omit the `date` object, as `moment.tz` defaults to the current time when you omit the first parameter.

Answer (score 4):

London Time / BST:

```js
const now = new Date();
console.log(now.toLocaleString('en-GB', { timeZone: 'Europe/London' }));
```

Comment: This is the way in 2023.

Comment: +1 ..I had to do `const newNow = new Date(now.toLocaleString('en-GB', { timeZone: 'Europe/London' }))` to save to db as a DateTime.